# C++ print string n times with white space between?

Tags: c++

Is there any way to print a string on c++ n times.
For example

```
int main(){
    int n = 5;
    cout << string(n, '|') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output is `|||||`, but desired output is `| | | | |`
Since string() cannot take whitespace " ", if I want to add whitespace in between, how can i approach that?

Comment: What do you mean by "string() cannot take whitespace" exactly?

Comment: Did you mean to use `' '` instead of `'|'`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz for ```string(n, '|')```, it seems that in ' ', it only takes one character, if I do ``` '| ' ```, it wont compile.

Comment: @Alex Well, yeah, that's because `'` is used for character constants in C++. `"` is used for string constants. It has nothing to do with whitespace.

Comment: That prints a string with n characters once. If you want to do something n times, use a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard algorithm `fill_n` for that

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int const n = 5;
    std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>{std::cout, " "}, n, '|');
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: TIL, Thank you. This is much neater than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can define our own `String` function for this purpose as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string String(int n, string a){
    string s = "";    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) s += a;
    return s;
}

int main(){
    int n = 5;
    cout << String(1,"|") + String(n - 1, " |") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
| | | | |
```

**Please note that** this time we can pass a `string` to our `String` function and not a character